# php DOMImplementation self closing tags

Tags: php, html, dom, tags

I need to create self closing tags using php DOMImplementation , but I dont know how.
I have this peace of code

```
$doc = new DOMImplementation();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->formatOutput = true;


//create and set doctype for html5
$doctype = $doc->createDocumentType('html', '', '');
$doc = $doc->createDocument("", "", $doctype);

//here elements are created
$html = $doc->createElement("html");
$head = $doc->createElement("head");
$body = $doc->createElement("body");

$css = $doc->createElement("link",'');
$css->setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
$css->setAttribute("href", "code.css");
$css->setAttribute("type", "text/css");

$head->appendChild( $css );

$html->appendChild( $head );

$html->appendChild( $body );

$doc->appendChild( $html );
$xml_string = $doc->saveHTML() ;
echo $xml_string;
```

but when I create the link element I get

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="code.css" type="text/css"></link>
```

how will I get

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="code.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: can you reproduce this? apparently, we can't http://codepad.viper-7.com/l2aiu9

Comment: if you use it on a server, and use a debugger(like firebug) to see the html document, you will see that what is getting produced is "<link rel="stylesheet" href="code.css" type="text/css"></link>"

Comment: first try to check the `view source` instead, kindly check on that. second, try (this is just a long shot) instead of this: `("link",'')`, change it to this `('link')`

Comment: i changed ("link",'') to ('link') and nothing changed, also if I use page source I get "<link rel="stylesheet" href="code.css" type="text/css">" but this is how the browser interprets this tag. If I save what is getting produced in a file(test.html) for example I have <link rel="stylesheet" href="code.css" type="text/css"></link>